# Ant war and ear is not generating

Tags: ant

I am new to this ant I wrote athe following build.xml file for generating war and ear. it is showing build successfull. but it not generating any war/ear file. I mentioned my script below. please help me what changes i have to do..
Thanks in advance....

```
<property name="src" value="src"/>
<property name="dst" value="web"/>
<property name="classes" value="WEB-INF/classes"/>
<property name="archiveName" value="medcardets"/>
<property name="archive" value="BuildArchive"/>



<fileset id="lib" dir="${dst}/WEB-INF/lib">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
</fileset>

<fileset id="war.file" dir="/">
        <include name="${archiveName}.war"/>
    </fileset>

 <fileset id="ear.file" dir="/">
        <include name="${archiveName}.war"/>
    </fileset>

 <fileset id="lib.rules" dir="${dst}/WEB-INF/lib/rules">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>


<fileset id="lib.j2ee" dir="j2ee">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>


<target name="clear">
    <delete dir="${dst}/${classes}"/>
    <delete dir="${archive}"/>
</target>


<target name="build" depends="clear">
    <mkdir dir="${dst}/${classes}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${dst}/${classes}" debug="on" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
        <classpath>
            <fileset refid="lib"/>
            <fileset refid="lib.rules"/>
            <fileset refid="lib.j2ee"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
    <copy todir="${dst}/${classes}">
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <exclude name="**/CVS"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: Which target do you think should build a WAR or EAR? All I see is compilation to produce classes and copying the classes

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for quick reply. i want to generate both war and ear. i wrote upto compilation process. after that I am unable to write code for generating war/ear file. as I already told you I am very new to this ant. could you please give a solution..

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies that you have written code that you expect to generate a WAR, but you have no instruction to do so. I see from your comment you are actually asking what the command should be.

Most important: I hope we are all new to things, after 35 years in the industry I learn something every day. Why did you ask the question rather than google? Learning to search is the most important skill. Google ant task WAR [gives this task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) with an example:

```
<war destfile="myapp.war" webxml="src/metadata/myapp.xml">
  <fileset dir="src/html/myapp"/>
  <fileset dir="src/jsp/myapp"/>
  <lib dir="thirdparty/libs">
    <exclude name="jdbc1.jar"/>
  </lib>
  <classes dir="build/main"/>
  <zipfileset dir="src/graphics/images/gifs"
              prefix="images"/>
</war>
```

and a similar entry for EAR:

```
<ear destfile="${build.dir}/myapp.ear" appxml="${src.dir}/metadata/application.xml">
      <fileset dir="${build.dir}" includes="*.jar,*.war"/>
    </ear>
```

Comment: i have a ant issue. Can you help me to resolve this. My SO Account is on hold. Where should i ask my question. Can i get your help ?